# Trying to delete duplicates with deleteOne() and/or deleteMany() but it's not deleting?

Tags: mongodb

I made several duplicates of the movie Howl's moving Castle and I try to delete with deleteOne and deleteMany. However, while I get "Acknowledge" but the delete count is still 0 and the movies haven't got deleted. And I wonder why? [Trying to delete duplicates][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DatT0.jpg

Comment: I'm taking a guess your collection is `movies` not `movie`. More than a guess is impossible with the provided information.

Comment: Yes my db is movies and the I added a var = movie10, which I tried to replace Howl's Moving Castle To another movie by overriding the variable. However, I realized it does not do that.

Comment: I was referring to your screenshot, it's missing an `s`, it's just `db.movie`

Comment: oh wow it was the one letter that I missed. smh Thank you very much for the thelp

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.